# redirection from non-www to www through HTTPS takes longer than HTTP

Tags: redirects, apache, https

I have enabled SSL for my site in the vhost file. I also have the redirection for the non-www to www over port 80:

```
<VirtualHost 62.210.85.6:80>
 ServerName pretty-story.com
 Redirect permanent / https://www.pretty-story.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

However it seems it takes a lot longer (about 2 seconds) to redirect from non-www to www over https.

So if I type `http://pretty-story.com`, it quickly resolves to `https://www.pretty-story.com` but if I type `https://pretty-story.com` it takes more than 2 seconds to resolve to `https://www.pretty-story.com` !

I tried to add the following :

```
<VirtualHost 62.210.85.6:443>
  ServerName pretty-story.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.pretty-story.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But then the website becomes inaccessible.

What should I do ?

Here's the results on pingdom (using Sweden because my CDN is only active in Europe):

- https://www.pretty-story.com  -> **874 ms**

  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/8cyCy/https://www.pretty-story.com
- http://www.pretty-story.com  -> **1.04s**

  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/laUz9/http://www.pretty-story.com
- http://pretty-story.com -> **947 ms**

  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/cohyrq/http://pretty-story.com
- https://pretty-story.com -> **2.51s** !!!!!!!!!!!

  https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/7s1PK/https://pretty-story.com

Comment: Highly recommend that you use multiple servers rather than just one server in Sweden. Use: https://www.webpagetest.org/ with multiple passes and multiple locations.

Comment: Sure, but pagespeedinsight gives me the same result. It tells me to improve server response time whenever I test with the url https://pretty-story.com

Comment: found the answer in this post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/653923/force-https-and-www-with-virtual-host-apache2/653947#653947    I needed to add SSL settings to HTTPS vhost redirection too

Comment: Sam, if you found a suitable answer you can quoteblock the source as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is detailed here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/653923/force-https-and-www-with-virtual-host-apache2/653947#653947

The key thing was to  have 3 VirtualHost :

- one for the http to https redirection
- one for the https non-www to www redirection, **which includes all the SSL settings**
- one for the https www version, which contains all the SSL settings + anything else you want.